# PropertyTypeDescriptor and Spring 3.1.2

Tags: spring, apache-flex

I'm working on a project using Spring-Flex 1.5.2 and Spring 3.1.2 and recently after adding some DAO's to my project i started getting this error on the WebLogic Console when trying to populate one of my combos:

```
[BlazeDS]org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.flex.core.io.HibernateProxyConverter.convert(HibernateProxyConverter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:35)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:171)
    at org.springframework.flex.core.io.SpringPropertyProxy.getValue(SpringPropertyProxy.java:160)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writePropertyProxy(Amf3Output.java:601)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeCustomObject(Amf3Output.java:532)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeObject(Amf3Output.java:207)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeObjectArray(Amf3Output.java:854)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeAMFArray(Amf3Output.java:445)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeObject(Amf3Output.java:193)
    at flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection.writeExternal(ArrayCollection.java:97)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writePropertyProxy(Amf3Output.java:594)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeArrayCollection(Amf3Output.java:476)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeObject(Amf3Output.java:189)
    at flex.messaging.messages.AbstractMessage.writeExternalBody(AbstractMessage.java:705)
    at flex.messaging.messages.AbstractMessage.writeExternal(AbstractMessage.java:435)
    at flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage.writeExternal(AsyncMessage.java:140)
    at flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage.writeExternal(AcknowledgeMessage.java:94)
    at flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessageExt.writeExternal(AcknowledgeMessageExt.java:55)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writePropertyProxy(Amf3Output.java:594)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeCustomObject(Amf3Output.java:532)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output.writeObject(Amf3Output.java:112)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf0Output.writeObject(Amf0Output.java:206)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageSerializer.writeObject(AmfMessageSerializer.java:196)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageSerializer.writeBody(AmfMessageSerializer.java:186)
    at flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageSerializer.writeMessage(AmfMessageSerializer.java:142)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:198)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$25364767.service(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:283)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:256)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:176)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:35)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    ... 57 more
```

Google has failed me on this one... so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have annotated my services with @RemotingDestination and created the Remote Objects in my Mxml, like this:

```
<s:RemoteObject id="marketSegment" destination="marketSegmentServiceImpl" endpoint="http://localhost:7001/scpi/messageBroker/amf"></s:RemoteObject>
```

then i'm adding this on my combobox:

```
dataProvider="{marketSegment.findAllCatalogs.lastResult}"
```

and this on my creationComplete:

```
private function init():void{
    marketSegment.findAllCatalogs();
    biotech.findAllCatalogs();
}
```

This is working to fetch obects that have only primitive type properties, but fails with the mentioned error when trying to fetch any object with complex type properties.

Comment: When do you get that error?  What code are you using to try to "populate one of my combos"?

Comment: i added the code im using on the flex side, also what i noticed on simple vs complex type properties. Thanks!

Comment: I was assuming this was a Java error; in which case I'm not sure how the Flex code will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some versions are incompatible.

The class `org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor` was removed in Spring 3.1!

Have a look at the jar that contains `org.springframework.flex.core.io.HibernateProxyConverter`.
Maybe you find in the pom.xml the version of spring-core  that is needed.