# Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

i am having some weird behavior with spring security.

When i load the application i get an exception

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor

WEB.XML:

> ```
> <web-app>
> <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
>  <filter>
>   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping> 
>  <servlet>
>  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class> org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet </servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationSecurityContext.xml</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>       
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

POM.XML:

> ```
>       <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>         <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
>     </dependency>  
>       <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
>     <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
> <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
> <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168215/propertytypedescriptor-and-spring-3-1-2

Comment: For starters you are mixing Spring Security versions (3.1.0 and 3.1.4) never mix different versions of a framework. Fix that, also make sure that you don't pull in mixed versions of Spring jars (check with `mvn dependency:tree`), if so explicitly define the versions you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PropertyTypeDescriptor and Spring 3.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168215/propertytypedescriptor-and-spring-3-1-2) the problem is that as of `spring-core 3.1.0.RELEASE` the `PropertyTypeDescriptor` was removed.

And `spring-security-core 3.1.0.RELEASE` depends on `spring-core 3.0.6.RELEASE` as the [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom) states.

Thus the NoClassDefFoundError.

I would recommend to downgrade to `spring-core to 3.0.6.RELEASE`.

`spring-security` updated the dependency to spring 3.2.4.RELEASE a few days ago. 
Take a look at the comments in github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security

> "SEC-2294: Update Spring Version to 3.2.4.RELEASE     23 days ago"

Answer (score 0):

EnvironmentAware is located in the spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, so you are missing that one.

Also recheck your Maven POM file so that you are not missing any other Spring library, like spring-web, spring-webmvc (you may have these since the DispatcherServlet class if found), spring-orm if you use an ORM like Hibernate, spring-jms if you use JMS, etc